# Как искать в базе данных совпадения от даты до даты?

Tags: php, sql, mariadb, redbeanphp

Всем привет, сижу где-то 2+ часов с проблемой. Суть такая: Есть база в которой есть 3 главных столбца по которым идёт поиск, к примеру: *Nick* (текст, например: Dima_Dima), *IP* (ip адрес, например: 111.111.111.111), *Data* (тут хранятся даты формата 1/2/2020, но ТИП столбца *TEXT*).

Скажу заранее, использую библиотеку **RedBeanPHP**.

Я делаю фильтр по параметрам указанным выше. По *NICK* и *IP* он фильтрует и выводит, но с *Data* проблемы.
Полазив по интернету я пришел к выводу, что подойдет вот такой **SQL** запрос: `select * from baza DATE(Data) BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-03-30'`

Но так как у меня столбец в формате *TEXT*, а не *DATA*, он не выполнит запрос.

Суть вопроса: Можно ли как-то сделать поиск от даты до даты если столбец в формате *TEXT*, а если нет, то как мне переформировать столбец под формат *DATA* (xxxx-yy-zz) и вообще, правильный ли **SQL** запрос у меня составлен, или он не будет работать?

Заранее спасибо за любую помощь!

Comment: нет нельзя. надо поменять тип столбца на date

Comment: @Ипатьев Окей, попробую изменить столбец под нужный формат. SQL команда верна для поиска в базе?

Comment: "пробовать" не надо. Это не выбор между сортами мороженого, "ладно я попробую клубничное". Это ответ на вопрос сколько будет 2x2 Не надо выбирать между 4 и 20. Запрос правильный, только date() убрать, просто `Data BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-03-30'`

Comment: @Ипатьев Под "попробую" я подразумевал то, что именно попробую изменить данные под нужный формат, получится или нет. А не в том плане, о котором говорили вы.